# Site renders incorrect on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, ios, wordpress

Right margin of my site is cut off on iphone.. any ideas? Thanks!

http://speedsociety.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom style sheet for the iPhone and attach it as so:

```
<?php
  $browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    if ($browser == true){
    $browser = 'iphone';
  }
?>

<?php if($browser == 'iphone'){ ?> <!-- Attach style-sheet here -- <?php } ?>
```